# How to show optgroup label+value in jQuery select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using a jQuery plugin named [Select2](https://select2.org/), in which I am using `Multiselect`. Previously I was also using the same plugin for my another website **but that one is quite old now**. I want, when I am selecting options from drop-down is shows with `optgroup` like this : [Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1WaY.jpg)
Now this plugin which I am using now is showing me like this : [Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TiMh.jpg)
I want that optgroup tag with value on selection.
Here is the working demo of `select2` : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhkdotme/rLmztr2d/343/)

Previously I was using this script to show optgroup with value :

```
function format(item) {
  opt = $(item.element);
  sel = opt.text();
  og = opt.closest('optgroup').attr('label');
  return og+' | '+item.text;
}
$("select").select2({
  formatSelection: format,
  escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
});
$(".select2_sample3").select2({
  tags: []
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `templateSelection`

And this is working example based on your code

```
function formatState (item) {
  opt = $(item.element);
  og = opt.closest('optgroup').attr('label');
  return og+' | '+item.text;
};

$('#example').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select a Category',
  templateSelection: formatState
});
```

jsfiddle  : https://jsfiddle.net/synz/t2zqjdf0/

resource : https://select2.org/selections#templating

Comment: Yes you're right, perfectly working for me. Thank you.